# Заменить текст одной переменной на текст другой регулярные выражения javascript

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, str-replace

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите, как реализовать. Имеется две переменные. В первой только текст с определенным разделителем. Допустим разделитель "|", а в другой переменной лежит html код. И в первой и во второй переменной количество текста одинаковое. Как можно заменить одно на другое?

Запутано объяснил. Вот такой пример:

```
var str = 'text1|text2|text3|text4|text5';
var html = 'just1<p>just2<span>just3</span>just4</p>just5';
```

Чтоб на выходе было примерно так: `text1<p>text2<span>text3</span>text4</p>text5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var str = 'text1|text2|text3|text4|text5';
var html = 'just1<p>just2<span>just3</span>just4</p>just5';

var seps = html.match(/<[^>]+>/g), i = 0;
console.log(str.replace(/\|/g, m => seps[i++]));
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!